# RxSwift convert Observable<Bool> to Observable<Void>

Tags: ios, swift, generics, sequence, rx-swift

I am not so convinced with RxSwift yet, and it's really hard to cleat understanding. After reviewing different materials, I cant' still work and manipulate sequences.
On the whole I have problem with type converting:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 'Observable<Bool>' to return type 'Observable<Void>' (aka 'Observable<()>')
```

I have CocoaAction processing, and should return `Observable<Void>`

```
func stopProject() -> CocoaAction {
    return CocoaAction { _ in
        let stopProject = stop(project: self.projectId)
        return stopProject.asObservable() //wrong converting
    }
}
```

The `stop` function return `Observable<Bool>`

**Finish view:**

```
    return stop(project: self.projectId).flatMap { _ in
        Observable<Void>.empty()
    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```swift
let voidObservable = boolObservable.map { Void() }
```

Comment: Yes, in some case you are right. I have found hint in https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1206

Comment: The following code worked for us : .map { _ in Void() }, it looks like you may need empty parameters, the code you mentioned doesn't work and fails with : 'Contextual type for closure argument list expects 1 argument, which cannot be implicitly ignored"

Answer (score 3):

`let voidObservable = boolObservable.map { _ in Void() }`

And in the case that you only want to emit a value if the boolean value is true:

`let voidObservable = boolObservable.filter { $0 }.map { _ in Void() }`

Answer (score 1):

Adding this extension:

```
public extension ObservableType {
    func mapToVoid() -> Observable<Void> {
        return map { _ in }
    }
}
```

so you could do

```
myObservable.mapToVoid()
```